# When to trust the result of numerical integration in mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration

How does one know when to trust the result of numerical integration, using NIntegrate, for higher (5 or 6) dimensional integrals in mathematica? For example, I get the following result

```
Integrate[ Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, {c, -2, 2}] // N

(* 30.1462 *)
```

whereas if I do the same integral numerically, I get

```
NIntegrate[ Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, {c, -2, 2}] // N
```

> During evaluation of In[2]:= NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy
> GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected
> to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one
> of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified
> precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise)
> smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of
> the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent
> numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 30.14615590437465 and
> 0.0001823733624988688 for the integral and error estimates.

```
Out[2]= 30.1462
```

This seems to indicate that one can trust the result of `NIntegrate` if the error estimate is a small percentage (~1%) of the estimated value of the integral. If that's true then how would one understand the discrepancy in the values obtained in the following two cases when Mathematica does not report any errors.

```
NIntegrate[ Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, {c, -2, 2}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"] // N

(* 298.918 *)

NIntegrate[ Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, {c, -2, 2}, Method -> "MonteCarloRule"] // N

(* 313.592  *)
```

In the following example, I also get a result with an error bar that is a small (~2%) percentage of the value of the integral

```
In[7]:= NIntegrate[ Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"] // N
```

> During evaluation of In[7]:= NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge
> after 1000100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 0.29686054547957375 and
> 0.005304460608762476 for the integral and error estimates.

```
Out[7]= 0.296861
```

but comparing it with the following analytic evaluation of the integral

```
Integrate[ Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}] // N

(* 31.0063 *)
```

we see that the answer is way off. Any guidance in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Beautifully speaking, it is exactly the place where science turns into art. But to be serious, the numerical calculation of an integral is always an estimate rather than a precise result. Various methods may yield results that differ somewhat from one another. That's normal. There are tutorials where the questions of this kind are discussed in detail with numerous examples. Have a look at the tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.

Comment: It helps to know something about your integrand, especially if it has large values only in a small region. E.g `NIntegrate[
 Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, -2, 0.3,
   2, 5}, {z, -5, -2, 0.1, 2, 5}, {a, -5, -2, 0.5, 2, 5}, {b, -5, -2, 
  0.2, 2, 5}, {c, -5, -2, 0.1, 2, 5}, 
 Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"]` or `NIntegrate[
 Exp[-a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 
  5}, {z, -5, 5}, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}, 
 Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", 
 Exclusions -> a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4]`

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thanks! If I keep everything else as in the last example (In[7]) above but additionally set MinRecursion to 1, it gives me a value close to the value obtained from integrating analytically (with some error estimates). Is it true then that in general, one can trust the output of NIntegrate if the error estimate is a small percentage (1-2%) of the value of the integral?

Comment: @Ibrazhehs I think you demonstrated convincingly that it is *not* true in general. In fact, there is no general answer. That's what Alexei was trying to convey: when to trust a numerical method is a hard problem in and of itself. I am not sure that there are quick shortcuts to the answer.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the Monte Carlo methods. `"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"` does very poorly on this example. `Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^7}` gives `0.33` and no error — so clearly unreliable. OTOH, `Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "Partitioning" -> {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}}` does something like my previous comment and gives a pretty good result. High-dimensional integrals can be hard, it seems, but I don't have a lot of experience with them.

Comment: Try increasing the `WorkingPrecision` and see how that affects the result. Also increase the number of function evaluations.